# Why is dns.resolveMx always returning an error when called many times?

Tags: node.js, dns

I am trying to validate a list of email addresses (to get rid of spammy ones e.g. asdasdas@waqwqasd.com) by looking up MX records with Node.JS

My code works on one email address but when I'm calling it a lot of times I get an error from `dns.resolveMx` with either ETIMEOUT or ECONNREFUSED.

Here's the relevant bits:

This test code works:

```
(function() {
  var dns = require('dns'); 
  var email = "test@yahoo.co.uk"
   var emailDomain;
    try
    {
      emailDomain = email.split('@')[1];

      console.log('Checking Domain ' + emailDomain);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      return false;
    }
  dns.resolveMx("yahoo.co.uk", function (err, addresses) {
      if(err)
      {
        console.log(err);
      }
      else
      {
        console.log('Found addresses ' + JSON.stringify(addresses));  
        return true;
      }
    }
  );
})();
```

This code doesn't:

```
(function() {

  var dns = require('dns');
  var fs = require('fs');
  var Sync = require('sync');

  var validEmails = [];
  var invalidEmails = [];
  var validDomains = [];

  var checkEmails = function()
  {
    var fileData = fs.readFileSync('emails_only-full.txt').toString().split('\n');

    console.log(fileData.length);
    testValidEmailDomains(fileData);
  }

  var finished = function()
  {
    console.log('Finished parsing database');
    console.log('Found ' + validEmails.length + ' valid emails');
    console.log('Found ' + invalidEmails.length + ' invalid emails');    
  };

  var testValidEmailDomains = function(emails, index)
  {
    if(emails.length == 0)
    {
      finished();
      return;
    }

    var email = emails.pop();
    var emailDomain;
    try
    {
      emailDomain = email.split('@')[1];
      if(validDomains.indexOf(emailDomain) != -1)
      {
        validEmails.push(email);
        return;
      }
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      invalidEmails.push(email);
      return;
    }
    console.log('Checking Domain ' + emailDomain);    
    dns.resolveMx(emailDomain, function (err, addresses) {
      if(err)
      {
        console.log(err);
        invalidEmails.push(email);
      }
      else
      {
        validDomains.push(emailDomain);
        validEmails.push(email);
        console.log('Found addresses ' + JSON.stringify(addresses));  
      }
      testValidEmailDomains(emails.slice(index), index + 1);
    });
  }
  checkEmails();
})();
```

I was thinking it was to do with calling too many times at once but using Sync/fibers to sleep the thread doesn't seem to work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: Appears stable branch (0.10.x) does not support `dns.setServers`. Use https://github.com/tjfontaine/node-dns instead for dns requests in this case. See the `dns.Request` method. It lets you manually set the dns server in each request.**

DNS servers typically block clients if too many requests are made in quick succession to avoid DNS amplification attacks. Best approach would be to:

- Rate limit DNS requests
- Use multiple servers and cycle through them (might still get blocked by ISP or other intermediaries)
- Cache domains that have already been checked to avoid duplicate requests

There's a good list of DNS servers here: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/a/free-public-dns-servers.htm

Sample code for cycling through multiple servers:

```
// static list of DNS servers to use from the list above
var SERVERS = ['8.8.8.8', ...];
var SERVERS_LENGTH = servers.length;

var dns = require('dns');

// function to resolve mx records   
// loops through emails and launches parallel requests - rate limit as required
function resolve(emails, fn) {
   emails.forEach(function(email, index) {
       var nextServer = SERVERS[index % SERVERS_LENGTH];
       dns.setServers([nextServer]);
       dns.resolveMx(email, fn);
   });
}
```

Comment: getting error : `dns` has no method 'setServers' http://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_resolvemx_domain_callback

Comment: Working for me on v0.11.13. Screenshot: http://s1291.photobucket.com/user/jksdua/media/dnssetservers_zpse43784e9.png.html

Comment: i am stuck with only stable releases :(

Comment: Just tested in node v0.10.15. You are right, it's not exposed. Use this: https://github.com/tjfontaine/node-dns. Example:

```js
var req = dns.Request({
  question: question,
  server: { address: '8.8.8.8', port: 53, type: 'udp' },
  timeout: 1000,
});

```